# Is Google read Model content (SEO Perspective)?

Tags: seo, google, local-seo

I have a one-page website. That is my personal website as a freelancer to find clients....

**Layout of My site**

> 1. Description about me
> 2. Services
>
>    Web Design Service in India
>
>    WordPress Development Service in India
>
>    eCommerce Developemnt Service in India
> 3. Contact Me

I am targeting keywords like "Web Design Service in India", "WordPress Development Service in India", etc.

---

But to make design clear, it display just few words under each each services... Then there is a read more button.

Now the problem came....

I can load the Bootstrap model with content when clicking read more button (It is NOT via ajax.... Content loaded with page load even not visible to the user.....)

Will google read that content? Or I have to use separate pages for each each services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will read the content.

No, it won't find clients for you.

Comment: No, it won't find clients for you.?? It means it is impossible that traget keyword like "Web Design Service in India" with one page website?

Comment: Theoretically, its possible yes. Practically, I have my doubts. Do a quick Google and see who are already doing this. I did a quick check, and the first 4 results are all ads (and that is currently taking up all the space above the fold). The rest below have been sitting on that space for quite some time (including Indiamart).

Comment: Another check on Google Trends showed that not a lot of people search for this phrase. Adwords can give more data, and you probably should look up the search volumes and the number of sites who are already being listed before you do this. If you do manage to get listed on the first page on the keyword, let me know - do I have a whole lot of search visibility stints for you!

Comment: If your website is mobile, Google sees and reads the content after the fold. Read more http://www.thesempost.com/google-updates-seo-advice-tabbed-content-mobile-first/